# Getting unwanted data after crawling website

Tags: python, regex, beautifulsoup, web-crawler

[image: Code[][1]]

I am crawling a website in which i am getting unwanted data like `\r\n` and I am using `.split()` and `.replace` method on the string but its not working. Below is the code and the output that I am getting-

```py
for i in url_event_final:
    res2 = requests.get(i)
    source2 = res2.content
    try:
        event_title = str((re.findall(r'class="header-mega">(.*?)</h1>', str(source2), re.DOTALL)[0])).replace('\r\n', '').strip()
        print(event_title)
    except Exception as e:
        try:
            event_title = str((re.findall(r'3-4 mobile-lg-1-1">(.*?)</h1>', str(source2), re.DOTALL)[0])).strip().replace('\r\n', '').replace('\r', '')

        print(event_title)
    except:
        try:
            event_title = (re.findall(r'3-4 mobile-lg-1-1">(.*?)\s</h1>', str(source2), re.DOTALL)[0]).replace('\r\n', '').strip()
            print(event_title)
        except Exception as e:
            event_title = (' ')
```

**OUTPUT**

```
\r\n Wat is er te zien in het Rijksmuseum?\r\n \r\n Dankzij Waller 2010-2020\r\n \r\n Hoogtepunten van Italiaanse tekeningen in het Rijksmuseum\r\n \r\n Nieuwe presentaties in het Aziatisch Paviljoen\r\n \r\n Reizende tentoonstelling Schatten uit het Rijks\r\n \r\n Muziekparade\r\n \r\n Hollandse meesterwerken op Schiphol\r\n \r\n XXL Papier\r\n \r\n Willem Diepraam, 50 jaar fotografie\r\n \r\n Tentoonstelling Slavernij in het Rijksmuseum\r\n
```

Answer (score 0):

you can have several lines of code to strip these characters. Try out:

```
 eventTitle = [x.strip('\n') for x in eventTitle]
 eventTitle = [x.strip('\r') for x in eventTitle]
```

Comment: did you get rid of .replace? Also what was the output when you tried this

Answer (score 0):

I don't have your source html file. Try the below solution.
regex is `'\r\n(.*)\r\n'`.

[image: solution output]

Python version is 3.7. I hope this helps.

Comment: not working.... regex of '\r\n(.*)\r\n' is not treated as text....Its not giving any output

Comment: for me the output is showing without \r\n as per the screenshot which i attached above. try this logic pass the event_title object to newevent =re.findall('\r\n(.*)\r\n', event_title). print(newevent)

Comment: I have done exactly same but it not worked....It has some issues related to unicode as the original source file doesn't contain "\r'\n"..It is a html code tag which is not present in the text format.....Are you getting my point??